# Partition that spans multiple disks

Tags: linux, storage, lvm

I want to have one partition that will span multiple disks.
I don't care about redundancy but in case one of the disks fails i still want to be able to access the data that is not on the damaged disk.
I've read that using LVM you can span a partition over multiple disks but if one disk fails, you might lose all the data on the whole partition.
RAID5 i'm not interested in it because i lose 1 disk for redundancy which is not important to me.

Note: these disks will be in a linux box.

Edit: What i want to achieve is to have a volume on which i will store various files and i want this volume to be easily expandable by adding disks to the volume. An important factor is that if i lose one disk from the volume, only the data written on that disk should be lost and not the entire volume. A 2nd factor to consider is that i don't need redundancy so a RAID5 for example is not appealing to me because i lose 1 disk for redundancy and the smallest disk is considered as base size.

Comment: A partition cannot span multiple disks. LVM can create a logical volume across multiple disks, not a partition.

Comment: Yes, it was a bad word choice.

Comment: As far as i know LVM will keep the metadata spread across the disks and because of this, if a disk fails the volume might be un-usable. Is it possible with LVM to have the metadata redundant so that if a disk fails only the data on that disk will be lost?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what exactly you want to do. How is having a directory on one partition and a subdirectory on another not do what you need? Why does this need to be a logical volume? Also, please remove mention of partitions because it is very misleading (and probably why you have been downvoted). Clearly explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is a very relevant question 6 years later given the availablity of capacities in the 10's of TiB's for less than USD1K.  I would expect an LVM partition to span as many physical disks as it needs to (linear volume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found what I was looking for: "[[mhddfs](https://romanrm.net/mhddfs)] is a FUSE filesystem module which allows to combine several smaller filesystems into one big “virtual” one".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the flavor of linux you're running, you should be able to pool the disks.

- [Red Hat's page on LVM pooling](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/chap-Virtualization_Administration_Guide-Storage_Pools-Storage_Pools.html)
- [FreeBSD's page on zpool](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zpool&sektion=8)

There are also 3rd party tools that will let you do this:

- [FlexRAID](http://www.flexraid.com/download/) (commercial) will allow you to pool data and ensure all data is retained
- [SnapRAID](http://snapraid.sourceforge.net/) may do this as well, though I cannot confirm at this time

Comment: The box is running Debian linux.

Comment: @AlexLinte which filesystem are you using?

Comment: I'm not bound to a certain FS (only FS available in Debian). It can be either ext,reiser,nfs,xfs.

Comment: Then in that case I highly recommend you read over this thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/241659/do-you-lose-everything-when-you-have-a-hard-disk-failure-in-a-multi-hard-disk-lv; it should provide you some insight into managing data over a spanned (Non-RAID) volume.

Comment: And while I can't directly give a biased answer to this, I've used FlexRAID myself and have benefited from the fact that it pools the disks on _top_ of the existing filesystem. You may want to have a look there.

Comment: I'm not looking for a commercial solution. I know the issues with LVM and that it stripes the data and metadata across the disks. If it could serialize instead of stripe that would be the solution for me.

Comment: So what i want to go after is a basic disk space concatenation. If a disk fails, only data that is whole or partially stored on that disk will be lost. I'm not interested in I/O performance like striping.

Comment: Unfortunately to my knowledge [there is no built in functionality with LVM to do that](http://superuser.com/questions/512228/lvm-without-stripe). You're going to need a 3rd party tool to do it -- be that open source or paid.